# How to get all nodes with xpath and return as resposeXML to js?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

How to retrieve xml using xpath and send back to client js as responseXML?

I have php as the server, js as the client, need the specified data and display as html table.

here's my xml

```
// goods.xml
<items>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone X</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone 7</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone 8</itemname>
    <itemqty>2</itemqty>
  </item>
</items>
```

I want those item with over 10 quantities, I was only able to get only one of them with my php file

```
// handle.php
$xmlFile = "../../data/goods.xml";
$doc->load($xmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFile, NULL, TRUE);
$nodes = $xml->xpath("/items/item[itemqty>10]");
echo $doc->saveXML($xpathresultset->item(0)); // send the xml response back to the client
```

Then I only got the first result, I couldn't get both result (id 1 & id 2)

```
<item>
   <id>1</id>
   <itemname>Apple iPhone X</itemname>
   <itemqty>20</itemqty>
</item>
```

But I want

```
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone X</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone 7</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more easily done using `DOMDocument` than `SimpleXML`, as you can then use `xpath` to search for nodes with `itemqty <= 10` and remove them from the document:

```
$xml = '<items>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone X</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone 7</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone 8</itemname>
    <itemqty>2</itemqty>
  </item>
</items>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('/items/item[itemqty<=10]') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $doc->C14N();
```

Output:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone X</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <itemname>Apple iPhone 7</itemname>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
  </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Thanks! @Nick Now I got another problem of updating a node value and saving the xml....